# Gendern generischer Feminina

Tags: gender-neutrality

Bislang werden üblicherweise nur generische Maskulina durch Einfügung von "*inn" oder ähnlichem gegendert, um deutlich zu machen, das trotz des grammatikalisch männlichen Geschlechts ausdrücklich auch Frauen mit gemeint sind, zum Beispiel:

- Patienten -> Patient*innen
- Benutzerberatung -> Benutzer*innenberatung

In einer konsequent geschlechtergerechten Sprache müssten entsprechend auch generische Feminina gegendert werden, um deutlich zu machen, dass trotz des grammatikalisch weiblichen Geschlechts auch Männer mit gemeint sind. Welche Möglichkeiten gibt es da?

- Personen -> Person???en
- Fachkräftemangel -> Fachkräft???mangel

Comment: Der Vergleich hinkt: Der Mensch -> die Menschin??? *Die Person* ist kein generisches Feminin

Comment: Des weiteren: fühlst du dich bei dem Begriff *Person* nicht angesprochen, weil er grammatikalisch weiblich ist?

Comment: @miep   Na, diese Frage kannst du umgekehrt auch stellen. Das "Bürgerbüro" meiner Stadt versucht aber neuerdings, diesen Begriff krampfhaft zu vermeiden. Auch "Rednerpult" ist inzwischen verpönt. Man soll lieber "Redepult" sage. Somit finde ich Tilmans Frage durchaus berechtigt.

Comment: Es ist schon seltsam. Da sagt sich jemand sinngemäß: „Okay, Leute, dann mache ich halt mit beim Gendern" und fügt berechtigterweise hinzu: „Aber wenn schon, dann bitte konsequent, und zwar auch bei Wörtern femininen Geschlechts“, und dann wird er wegen eben dieser Konsequenz kritisiert. Mal ehrlich, ob hier nun der Begriff *generisches Femininum* richtig oder falsch ist, sei einmal dahin gestellt, aber die Frage an sich ist doch völlig berechtigt: entweder man gendert ganz oder gar nicht, nur wie macht man es ganz? Von mir gibt es ein +1.

Comment: @miep "Mensch*innen" kommt durchaus vor.

Comment: Warum wollen 3 Leute diese Frage mit der Begründung "Opinion based" schließen? Von welchen Meinungen könnte die Beantwortung abhängen? Das Thema lässt sich mit ganz sachlichen Argumenten behandeln, frei von allen persönlichen Meinungen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Vorschlag zur Güte: *Redn-Sie-Pult*.

Answer (score 8):

Du gehst von der nicht weiter hinterfragten Prämisse aus, es gäbe so etwas wie generische Feminina. Diese Prämisse trifft aber nicht zu. Daher ist deine Frage ebensowenig beantwortbar wie die Frage, warum der Mond ausgerechnet aus Käse ist. Es gibt keine generische Feminina und der Mond ist aus Gestein.

Generische Maskulina erkennt man daran, dass es eine Möglichkeit gibt, davon eine weibliche Form abzuleiten:

- Singular: der Arbeiter → die Arbeiterin
- Plural: die Arbeiter → die Arbeiterinnen

ebenso: Patient, Benutzer usw.

Das Wort *»die Kraft«* ist kein Wort mit einem generischen Geschlecht, denn es gibt keine Möglichkeit, davon eine Form mit einem anderen Geschlecht abzuleiten. Das gilt auch, wenn dieses Wort der letzte Bestandteil eines Kompositums wie z.B. *»die Fachkraft«* ist. Damit kann man zwar sowohl männliche als auch weibliche Personen bezeichnen, das grammatische Geschlecht des Wortes ist aber in beiden Fällen weiblich. (Auch die grammatisch sächlichen Wörter *»das Weib«* und *»das Mädchen«* bezeichnen Personen, bei denen das biologische Geschlecht nicht mit dem grammatischen übereinstimmt.)

Für das Wort *»die Person«* gilt genau dasselbe.

Es gibt aber auch sächliche Wörter, die man gleichermaßen für männliche wie für weibliche Personen verwenden kann:

- das Baby
- das Kind
- das Genie
- das Naturtalent

Wenn eines dieser Wörter ein generisches Neutrum wäre, müsste es einen Weg geben, davon eine männliche Form und auch eine weibliche Form abzuleiten. Das ist aber nicht der Fall.

Und es gibt sogar mindestens ein männliches Wort, das für Personen beiderlei Geschlechts verwendbar ist, ohne das es sich dabei um ein generisches Maskulinum handelt (für weitere Beispiele in den Kommentaren wäre ich sehr dankbar):

- der Mensch

Eine *»Menschin«* gibt es nicht, daher ist das Geschlecht des Wortes *»Mensch«* kein generisches.

Deine Behauptung *»In einer konsequent geschlechtergerechten Sprache müssten entsprechend auch generische Feminina gegendert werden«* ist zwar politisch korrekt, aber ebenso sinnvoll wie die Forderung eines gesetzlichen Vaterschutzes (als Pendant zum Mutterschutz) für gebärende Väter. Man kann gerne beides fordern, und man kann das sogar als Gesetz formulieren, nur wird es in beiden Fällen niemals dazu kommen, dass solche Regeln auch angewendet werden können. Männer können nicht gebären und generische Feminina existieren nicht.

Comment: Die Antwort beschreibt das Problem, dass ich von vornherein mit der Frage hatte: dass sie von einer falschen Prämisse ausgeht. Und für die ausgezeichneten Vergleiche gibt's auf jeden Fall +1

Comment: Generisch heißt meines Wissens, dass es eine umfassende Kategorie ist. Das Kriterium, dass davon ein geschlechtsmarkierender Spezialfall ableitbar sein muss, sehe ich zum ersten Mal und ich bezweifle es. Ein weiteres Beispiel für ein männliches ist "der Gast", von den Misfits schon zur Gästin verballhornt. Von "die Ente" lässt sich ja "der Enterich" ableiten; das wäre also nach Deinen Kriterien schon ein generisches Femininum? Das widerspricht aber dem zweiten Satz Deiner Antwort.

Comment: Woher stammt die Definition, dass ein generisches Genus nur vorläge, wenn eine Form des anderen Genus daraus ableitbar wäre?

Answer (score 3):

Ich fürchte, die Frage, so einfach sie klingt, erforderte zur soliden Beantwortung eine sehr weitgehende Reform der Morphologie der deutschen Sprache. Denn eine Femininum-Zusatzendung wie *in lässt sich im Deutschen an Substantive zwar leicht anhängen. Umgekehrt, also Anhängen einer Maskulinum-Zusatzendung, ist es aber nicht so leicht.

Welche Möglichkeiten gäbe es also? Phantasieren wir mal:

**1) Weglassen aller Endungen und Neutralisierung des Artikels:**

- der Bürger --> das Bürg
- der Schreiner --> das Schrein
- der Teilnehmer --> das Teilnehm
- der Lehrer --> das Lehr
- die Person --> das Person
- die Fachkraft --> das Fachkraft

**2) Einführung einer neuen Universalendung und eines neuen Artikels für alle Geschlechteridentitäten**

- der Bürger --> dü Bürgü
- der Schreiner --> dü Schreinü
- die Person --> dü Person(ü?)
- die Fachkraft --> dü Fachkraftü

Ich nehme hier mal -ü/dü, weil mir das relativ neutral vorkommt. ä/dä wäre wohl schon zu nahe am Klang von -er/der.

Bei Person könnte das Neutral-ü vielleicht wegfallen, weil das Wort an sich nichts weiter zu einer Gender-Einordnung verrät. Bei *Fachkraft* habe ich das Gefühl, das Teilwort *Kraft* so stark die Genus-Konnotation "weiblich" mit sich trägt, dass eine explizite Neutralisierung notwendig ist. Das ist aber nur ein Gefühl, und so vorzugehen ist ein Bruch der Logik.

Die beiden Vorschläge oben sind natürlich nicht durchsetzbar. Ich führe sie nur des Gedankenexperiments wegen an. Wenn jemand bessere Ideen hat: Lasst hören!

Comment: +1 für "ü" statt "x"

Comment: Im vorletzten Absatz schreibst Du, die Endung erlaube die Gendereinordnung. Im Feminismus unterscheidet man zwischen Geschlecht und Gender, ersteres ist ein biologischer Sachverhalt, letzteres die soziale Rolle. Die Sprache stammt aber aus einer Zeiit, in der man sich noch keine Gedanken über das mögliche Auseinanderfallen dieser zwei Aspekte gemacht hat, sondern von einer Identität ausging. Wenn man bei einer Stellenausschreibung für einen Mathematiker die Rolle nicht an den Bewerber anpassen will bliebe man also bei Matehmatiker und als Mathematikerin könnte man sich auch mit Penis bewerben?

Comment: Der großartige [Hermes Phettberg](https://www.phettberg.at/index.html) verwendet recht konsequent deine Variante 2 mit y/ys: ein Heimhelfy, mehrere Heimhelfys.

Comment: Wie wäre es mit der Neutralisierung der generischen Substantive und Einführung einer neuen maskulinen Endung: das Lehrer, die Lehrerin, der Lehrerus; das Fachkraft, die Fachkräftin, der Fachkraftus?